# Line ending error on DACs in higher version of Visual Studio

Tags: acumatica

before, we use Visual studio 2013 and acumatica works fine but now we use Visual studio 2017 and opening the solution detects all DAC's line ending have unexpected characters, blank line endings that hinders building the project.

please see attached photo
https://1drv.ms/i/s!Anz1GGZnZ-16gmnnqeZ_p1fs1Job

Comment: Which Acumatica version are you using? I believe this is a known issue that was fixed in recent 5x and 6x versions.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen that occur if you use the Acumatica DAC generate class tool in visual studio.

To fix you delete all spaces/characters at the end of the file back to the ending namespace bracket "}" and save. Not sure what it adds to the cs file but I have seen this before and perform the step I listed above after each generate class.